# Ruby Rails install on OSX, new terminal requires bundle install again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have Ruby installed using RVM v1.25.30 (stable) on my OSX 10.9.4. I'm able to get everything working, but whenever I close my terminal and reopen it and try to run a command that worked before with the command `bundle exec spork`, I get the error:

```
bundler: command not found: spork
Install missing gem executables with 'bundle install'
```

I can go through the process of doing bundle install and resolve the issues, primarily with building `nokogiri` missing `libiconv`, but thats annoying to do every time.

My `.bash_profile` file looks like:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/usr/local/bin:~/bin:~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/gem:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 

source ~/.profile
```

My `.profile` file looks like:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

A few notes here. I'm using Ruby `v2.0.0p481`, Rails `v4.0.8`, rvm `v1.25.30`, Bundler `v1.6.2`. Also I'm following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does `bundle exec spork` work?

Comment: It does not, it gives me the error above that says `bundler: command not found: spork`

Comment: Does `bundle contents spork` show anything promising? Is there a `bin/spork` in that list? Also is `spork` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Did you use Oh My Zsh ? If yes you need to add this line in .zshrc

Comment: try `cd ../` and `cd <your-dir>` and then try bundle exec spork.